# Events System - Possible to publish another page when page is being published?

Tags: tridion

I have a question about the events system in Tridion 2011.....would it be possible to publish another page when other pages are sent to the publishing queue?

We currently have an XML file that defines our site navigation and sitemap, but unfortunately currently needs manually publishing each time a new page is added to the website.

My concern I have about auto-publishing from the events system as well is having to publish the same page several times, when really it would only need publishing after the final item in the publishing queue has ended its transaction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could publish the Sitemap per transaction (that can contain many pages, structure groups, etc.) by subscribing to the PublishTransaction Save event.

You could consider verifying the publish queue and see if there are waiting transactions, but in theory this could postpone the Sitemap to be published for a very, very long time.

```c#
EventSystem.SubscribeAsync<PublishTransaction, SaveEventArgs>(
    (subject, args, phase) =>
    {
        if (!PublishStransactionStateIsSuccessfullyCompleted(subject))
            return;

        // Code to publish sitemap
    },
    EventPhases.TransactionCommitted
);
```

```c#
static bool PublishStransactionStateIsSuccessfullyCompleted(PublishTransaction transaction)
{
    return transaction.State == PublishTransactionState.Success ||
            transaction.State == PublishTransactionState.Warning;
}
```

Comment: That's excellent, I've used this example to great effect as using the async event doesn't appear to clog up the publishing queue! Now just to figure out if the publish transaction is the last one in the queue and hey presto!

Answer (score 8):

Whenever you want to change how many items are being published by Tridion in response to a publish action, my mind immediately screams ***custom resolver***.

Chris Summers did a great write up of his experience with them a while ago: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/the-story-of-sdl-tridion-2011-custom-resolver-and-the-allowwriteoperationsintemplates-attribute

Nuno wrote his experience up a bit more concisely: http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2011/10/tridion-publisher-and-custom-resolvers.html

It sounds to me like you should simply add your navigation to the ResolvedItems collection there. If you use resolvers consistently, you also won't get this explosion of publish transactions that you seem worried about and instead will have all related items published (and deployed) in a single transaction.

Comment: Maybe indeed a custom resolver would be even better, but then the sitemap will be part of the transaction - and I liked Bart's suggestion to publish the sitemap with a lower priority. Not all sitemap builders out there are so fast .. Also when you unpublish a Page you want to republish your sitemap as well, and that's the opposite action as the resolver is handling at that time.

Comment: Fighting against the system is certainly a valid way to increase job security. I'd rather embrace the system and see this as a great opportunity to fix other problems: like the fact that the site map takes so long to generate. Then again, I'm also the guy that is slowly peeling layers of duct tape from his house and then has to call the handy man, because fixing leaks is one thing ***I*** can not do.

Comment: Depending on how the sitemap is generated and how heavy that is I was initially thinking of a Custom resolver myself too, but Richard clearly stated that his concern was that this Page should not be Published multiple times. A Custom resolver will Publish it with every Publish Transaction and if you Publish a lot of single Pages that might become an issue indeed.

Comment: Thanks for your help again. To be honest I wasn't aware of custom resolvers before reading Frank's answer so it has been pretty informative and a learning experience - all the same appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

This is something that comes up a lot of times during an implementation, certainly with navigation or sitemaps that are depending on published items (which is not an ideal situation in my opinion).

A possible solution for this would be that you use the Event System to place the Page which generates your XML in the Publishing Queue with low priority. This will make (somewhat) sure that it is only published after your regular publish actions are executed. Now secondly the event should check whether this Page is already in the queue, so it doesn't add it a second time.

Keep in mind, this does not prevent it from being published multiple times a day, but it should at least make sure it is never in the queue twice. On a fast system with a dedicated multi threaded publisher, it could very well mean that it still gets published every hour or so depending on your activity etc.

Another option would be to schedule publishing once a day of that Page, using the Event System to repeat that process, so that every day at the same time it is published only once. This will reduce your accuracy of your XML since it only gets updated once a day, but it will prevent your Publishing Queue from being filled too much might that be an issue.